# weblogic server clustered environment

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

Is it possible to have a singleton stateless session bean in an clustered environment in weblogic? so that my session beans only active only one server.

could you please tel me any idea .

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: In case you haven't realized, clustering is done for high-availability. Your design reduces the availability, so I doubt this is even feasible in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a singleton session bean deployed in an active-passive mode. It does reduce your scalability since you will only have one node in your cluster available.

You should look for Active-Passive Deployment in the Oracle Fusion Middleware/High Availability documentation.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10106/busreq.htm#ASHIA4447